# JavaScript: How to get data out from a non blocking call back

Tags: javascript, nonblocking

```
function getHtmlBodyFromFile( filename ){
    var outStr = '';
    $.get(filename, function(data, status) {
        outStr = $('body', $(data)).html();
    });
    return outStr;
}
$("div#detail").html( getHtmlBodyFromFile('OEBPS/text/section0002.xhtml') ); //blank
```

The return outStr is blank because the function return immediately after call to $.get()
Could you please suggest me a better way to do return with a valid data for those non-blocking style.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of expecting to return data from `getHtmlBodyFromFile` function, pass a callback function to `getHtmlBodyFromFile` which should be executed after the ajax call.

Something like this:

```
function getHtmlBodyFromFile( filename, callback ){
    var outStr = '';
    $.get(filename, function(data, status) {
        outStr = $('body', $(data)).html();
                callback(outStr)
    });
    //return outStr;
}
getHtmlBodyFromFile('OEBPS/text/section0002.xhtml', function(data) {
    $("div#detail").html(data);
});
```

Comment: This non-blocking style is very interesting Cybernate! I'm trying a small apps using this; come from embedded C language of return style.. this style doesn't feel familiar to me. Your answer opened my mind.. :) .. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), that will be much simple, that allows you to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted.

```
$("div#detail").load('OEBPS/text/section0002.xhtml body');
```

***PS:*** if you use id selector, you don't need to `$('div#detail')`, just `$('#detail')` would be better. Query dom by id is the fast way.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

use the `success` callback when using `$.get()`

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('div#detail').load('OEBPS/text/section0002.xhtml', function(response, status) {
    $(this).html($('body', $(response)));
});
```

Alternatively, you can load the fragment you want by adding `' body'` behind the URL, but with the callback you have the option to check the response status.